# How to get element class attribute with ExtJS 4.1.1 in a cross browser way?

Tags: class, internet-explorer-8, extjs4.1, getattribute

I just noticed that `Ext.get('myElement').getAttribute('class')` doesn't work with IE8-. Does anyone has an elegant alternative (ExtJS 4.1.1 native or patch prefered)? Maybe this feature is hidden somewhere in the framework?

---

### Edit

Here is the context. I have temporarily fixed the issue like this :

```
action.getAttribute('class') || action.dom.className
```

View (grid) :

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    items: [{
        icon: '/images/edit.png',
        iconCls: 'action-edit'
    }, {
        icon: '/images/delete.png',
        iconCls: 'action-delete'
    }]
}
```

Controller :

```
init: function () {
    this.control({
        'grid actioncolumn': {
            click: function (a, b, c, d, ev, record) {
                var action = Ext.get(ev.target);
                if (action.is('img')) {
                    action = action.getAttribute('class') || action.dom.className;
                    action = action.match(/action-(.+)/)[1];
                    this[action + 'Action'](record);
                }
            }
        }
    });
},

editAction: function (record) { 
    // ... 
},

deleteAction: function (record) { 
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: Waiting for someone to suggest using jQuery.

Comment: @Eric Hope your comment will be able to dissuade anyone from doing this :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop # from the node id and it'll probably work.

*UPDATE*: I'm still not sure what exactly you're trying to do. `Ext.get` returns `Ext.dom.Element` object, which wraps native element and provides a certain level of abstraction from DOM but still is pretty much low-level tool. Since older IE doesn't support 'class' attribute you'll have to call `getAttribute('className')` to get the result.

Or you can resort to using standard convenience methods like `hasCls` and `getStyle` for checking particular classes and styles on an element. To find elements with particular class there's `query` method. All in all I fail to see why exactly you would need to get the list of all classes defined on an element.

*UPDATE 2*: OK, now I get what you need. Your code is way too complex, it can be simplified like this:

CSS:

```
.action-edit, .action-delete {
    width: 16px; /* Or whatever fits your bill */
    height: 16px;
}

.action-edit {
    background-image: url('/images/edit.png');
}

.action-delete {
    background-image: url('/images/delete.png');
}
```

View:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    items: [{
        iconCls: 'action-edit',
        action: 'edit'
    }, {
        iconCls: 'action-delete',
        action: 'delete'
    }]
}
```

Controller:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'grid actioncolumn': {
            click: function(a, b, c, d, ev, record) {
                var target = Ext.get(ev.target);
                if (target && target.action) {
                    this[target.action + 'Action'].call(this, record);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Or it can be done in more officially supported way:

View:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    items: [{
        iconCls: 'action-edit',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex) {
            this.fireEvent('editAction', grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex));
        }
    }, {
        iconCls: 'action-delete',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex) {
            this.fireEvent('deleteAction', grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex));
        }
    }];
}
```

Controller:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'grid actioncolumn': {
            editAction: this.editAction,
            deleteAction: this.deleteAction
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously the view event handling code can be further abstracted, but the main idea here is that you shouldn't be afraid of hiding view complexities Controller has no need to know about.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake but I actually don't use `Ext.get()`, I just wanted to make things easier to understand. Anyway, I have updated my question according to your remark.

Comment: Hi :) I don't use `iconCls` to apply CSS styles, I just want to allow the controller to extract the name of the clicked action from the icon class. I do it this way because I tried to use an "action" property as you suggested firstly, but it is not accessible from the controller. Moreover, action column items seems not to be considered as components (ExtJS 4.1.1). That said, I like the second suggestion you made even if it's not fully MVC :D

Comment: @wared Using `iconCls` is better than `icon`, it allows you to change actual icons in the CSS sheet without changing the source. I just gave you an example of how it's done. As for actioncolumn properties not accessible from controller, I'll have to look into that.